# Removing a row in excel once a date has expired in a column

Tags: excel

I am setting up an excel list of VIP's that are staying at my hotel. The idea is to keep track of all arriving and in-house VIPs. Each row will list all the information of the VIP including departure date. I would like for excel to automatically remove the row for the VIP once the date rolls from the PC past the departure date. Forgive me if I am insulting your intelligence, in example, for the date of 7/2/15, all VIP's that were checking out of the hotel on 7/1/15 should no longer be on the Excel list once the date rolled to 7/2/15 at 12:00am.

I hope this helps. I am very excited for your assistance and reply. Thank you!

Comment: Will the workbook be open at this time ??

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Basic create a loop that goes through and checks to see if the date is past and then delete it.

```
 Dim i As Integer

 For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
     If *Date_is_Passed* Then
         ActiveSheet.Rows(rowToDelete).Delete
     End If  
  Next i
```

Once you delete the row, you have to reverse the loop (top down vs bottom up) or else the loop will skip the row right underneath the row you deleted. That row will take the place of the deleted row and will be skipped with your loop.

Comment: if you're going to delete rows, you'll get much better results if you go from the bottom (last row) up (first row)...just sayin'